# Cancel Image onload when component unmounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app where I load images using another component called `load-image`.

Now I pass `src` to `load-image`, it shows a nice loader till image loads, and when its loaded, it shows a nice animation of image.

The problem arises here. I opened the app page, All images start loading.
Now user goes to another page, the images are still loading. I can see them loading in the console. Now I get this error in console.

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined
>   component.

Here is my code.

```
export default class LoadImage extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      isMounted: false,
    };
    this.onImageLoad = this.onImageLoad.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const imgSrc = this.props.imageSrc;
    const img = new window.Image();
    img.onload = this.onImageLoad;
    img.src = imgSrc;
    this.setState({
      isMounted: true,
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({
      isMounted: false,
    });
  }

  onImageLoad() {
    const self = this;
    if (self.state.isMounted === true) {
      self.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    const self = this;
    const imageClasses = classNames({
      'image-loaded': self.state.isLoaded,
      'image': true,
    });
    const imgStyle = {
      backgroundImage: 'url("' + self.props.imageSrc + '")',
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      backgroundPosition: 'center',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      width: 'inherit',
      height: 'inherit',
    };
    return (
      <div className="image-loader">
        <div style={ imgStyle } className={ imageClasses }>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can i cancel older request so that they don't update state after unmounting. I am already using state to check if component is mounted or not. Thanks.

Comment: https://goo.gl/L0CHIX

Comment: How do i check if component is mounted or not ? I'm Following this: http://jaketrent.com/post/set-state-in-callbacks-in-react/

Answer (score 10):

You can change the callback while the image is still loading. In `componentWillUnmount`, set `this.img.onload` to a function that does nothing.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const imgSrc = this.props.imageSrc;
    this.img = new window.Image();
    this.img.src = imgSrc;
    this.img.onload = this.onImageLoad;

  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if ( ! this.img ) {
        return;
    }
    this.img.onload = function(){};
    delete this.img;
  }
```

Source:
https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso/blob/master/client/components/image-preloader/index.jsx

No need for isMounted() if you take this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `setState` in `componentWillUnmount`. If the component is about to unmount, there's no point altering its state since it's about to be removed from the DOM.